# How can I kill / murder / fully disable StickyKeys?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I hate StickyKeys. Worst idea Microsoft has ever come up with.

Is there any way to disable it permanently, system-wide?

Comment: Clippy.  Don't forget about your faithful, bendy, little friend.  Though sticky keys (or whichever shortcut is activated by holding shift) gets me EVERY time I reinstall Windows and hesitate on the shift key while thinking about my next action.

Comment: I understand the beef with sticky keys but not windows 8.

Comment: To be fair, stickykeys is a feature for users with a disability so they don't have to press multiple keys at once. I understand your hatred for it, but it has a very legitimate use.

Comment: @Nick - But it should be possible to disable.  I have a tremor, which makes the feature activate far too readily.  (But I did find out how to permanently disable it in Vista.)

Comment: Did no one ever click the shortcut in the Sticky Keys alert to go straight to the control panel in question?

Comment: Microsoft could easily have chosen a less commonly-used key to toggle sticky keys, like F4 or Caps Lock. @Amolain please accept the top answer.

Comment: indeed, real pain especially while playing games :P

Answer (score 60):

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.  In the Start menu type "sticky keys".
- Choose the option "Change how my keyboard works".
- You will find checkboxes for many accessibility options
- You must also then click "Set up sticky keys" to disable the shortcut forever.
- Uncheck the option that says "Turn on Sticky Keys when SHIFT is pressed five times."

Comment: Does this work for disabling on the login screen?

Answer (score 2):

Method 1: Keyboard Shortcut

Press both SHIFT keys at the same time. This reset everything to normal.
Method 2: Control Panel

```
Click Start → Control Panel → Ease of Access → Change how your keyboard works.
Locate the “Make it easier to type” heading.
Remove the check mark from the box next to “Turn on Sticky Keys”.
Press the OK button to save your changes.
```

If there is no check mark next to this option, Sticky Keys is not on.
Disable Sticky Keys Permanently

If you find the Sticky Keys feature particularly annoying, it can be turned off for good.

```
Click Start → Control Panel → Ease of Access → Change how your keyboard works.
Click “Set up Sticky Keys” (or press ALT+C).
If there is a check in the box labeled “Turn On Sticky Keys”, un-check it.
Un-check “Turn on Sticky Keys when SHIFT is pressed five times”.
Click the OK button to save your changes.
```

You have now prevented Sticky Keys from re-activating in the future.

Answer (score 1):

To Permanently delete Sticky keys:

Go to:
 `C:\WINDOWS\System32` and rename `sethc.exe`
This should now be permanently disabled.
enjoy.

Comment: I rename it, delete it, it always comes back