# CTRL locks when pressed

Tags: keyboard, ctrl, sticky-keys

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> it just locks and my PC thinks that the key is held. Then I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>. After I press that combination everything works fine until I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> again(sometimes it just locks automatically without pressing). I disabled Sticky keys everywhere, I pressed both <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, I Pressed <kbd>FN</kbd> - Nothing works! Please, any suggestions? Is my keyboard broken?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/484454/281154

Comment: When sticky keys are active you usually get audible feedback everytime you press Shift, Ctrl, Alt or Win. Are you getting this when you have you problem with Ctrl key? Is the problem specific only to Ctrl or Alt, and Shift are also affected? I am trying to understand if you problem is related to MS Windows Sticky Keys or something entirely different.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe Mode?

Answer (score 1):

I would see if I could find a keyboard testing program and see if the <kbd>FN</kbd> key is stuck.

I experienced a Laptop manufacturer with an undocumented BIOS feature that meant that if you hit <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> would become sticky. They even thought it was a bug, until they replaced my PC and the new one did the same, and they contacted the BIOS vendor to find that out.